# SQL 2012 Query to output to "table" column

Tags: sql-server, table-variable

I have prototype of SQL query (actual query is too huge to post)

```
SELECT Site, Risk_Time_Stamp,COMPUTER_NAME, [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],Number_of_Risks
    FROM dbo.sem_computer
    WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
    GROUP BY Site, Risk_Time_Stamp,COMPUTER_NAME, [IP_ADDR1_TEXT],Number_of_Risks
```

That outputs

```
Site    Risk_Time_Stamp COMPUTER_NAME   IP_ADDR1_TEXT   Number_of_Risks
16K987  Aug 14, 2015    ADBF8J2         10.90.0.52            2
16K987  Aug 14, 2015    AD25N10         10.51.0.80            1
16K987  Aug 14, 2015    N20C0F8J2       10.18.0.79            1
```

How to create query that will output site, along with column named `RISK STATISTICS` that has table, i.e.

```
SITE                          RISK STATISTICS
16K987  Risk_Time_Stamp COMPUTER_NAME   IP_ADDR1_TEXT   Number_of_Risks
        Aug 14, 2015    ADBF8J2         10.90.0.52            2
        Aug 14, 2015    AD25N10         10.51.0.80            1
        Aug 14, 2015    N20C0F8J2       10.18.0.79            1
```

@sean-lange
I'm trying to create a flat excel file to input in [Tableau](http://www.tableau.com/) . Each Site will be plotted on a map and if there are any risks, a hover-over will detail these.

A Site can have zero to many risks, hence the need for column with a `table` value, i.e. column with array value.

Comment: The query you posted won't run, you reference tables that aren't in the query. I suspect from your where clause that you are using the old style joins. The real problem though is that your question isn't at all clear. What is this "new" column? It looks just like the original output. The only difference I can see is that the first column only have a value for the first row. This kind of thing should be done in the presentation layer. If you need help you need to provide some details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange I updated the post. My actual query is too long. I'm trying to create a flat excel file to input into Tableau that will plot the site on a map, and if there are any risks, which computer, ip, time, and number of risks.

Comment: @SohniMahiwal is it fair if we can sort out this problem at front end

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense. What do you mean by a column with a table?? Are you trying to create a single column with all the values of those 4 columns? I can't figure out at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: @tinka How to sort out the problem at the front end? I mean, my intention was to create a flat input file to Tableau mapping and data software. But I'm up for ideas!

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I am trying to create single column will all the values of those 4 columns. Each column can have different number of values.

Comment: Why would you do that? What a bizarre requirement. You could do that using concatenation. SELECT Site, Risk_Time_Stamp + COMPUTER_NAME + [IP_ADDR1_TEXT] + Number_of_Risks

Comment: @SeanLange Management was requesting this. I am trying to find the best way to accomplish this. Concatenation? Let me try this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87593/discussion-between-sohni-mahiwal-and-sean-lange).